# 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' while saving data to core data

Tags: xcode, core-data

I have 2 classes which are Brand and Product. Brand has attributes: name and relationship(one to many) products to Product; while Product has attributes: name and relationship(one to one) brand to Brand.

Here is how error occurs:
There are 2 brands Brand1 and Brand2. When I save P1, P2... to Brand1, it works well. But if I try to save a new product to Brand2, shows me error:
`-[Brand compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

I searched the reason for a whole afternoon, no results. Anyone has any idea about how to solve this?

Here is the code of adding new product:

```
  - (void)addProduct:(NSString *)name brandOfProduct:(Brand *)brand
  {
      Product *newProduct = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:self.coreDataManager.managedObjectContext];
      newProduct.name = name;
      [brand addProductsObject:newProduct];
      NSError *error;
      [self.coreDataManager.managedObjectContext save:&error];
  }
```

The 'brand' here refer to the one user selected in a picker view,

```
Brand *brand = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:row];
```

**Update 1:** The error shows when `[self.coreDataManager.managedObjectContext save:&error];` is called for save the new product to Brand2.

error message:
`CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[Brand compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1092d97a0 with userInfo (null)`

**Update 2:** I found where causes this error:

```
  - (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
  {
      [self.tableView beginUpdates];
  }

  - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
  {
      UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

      switch(type) {
          case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
              [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
              break;

          case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
              [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
              break;

          case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
              [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
              break;

          case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
              [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
              [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
              break;
      }
  }

  - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
  {
      [self.tableView endUpdates];
  }
```

Comment: you should show some of your code.

Comment: @Volker Sorry, here is my code, please have a look.

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception? Did you auto generate the classes? Are the relationships inverse?

Comment: have you made sure that brand is really a `brand` object as well as that you run on the main thread? Where exactly is the error thrown?

Comment: @Wain yes, they are auto generated and the relationships are inverse. `CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.`
this is the error.

Comment: @Volker brand is really a `brand`, the error shows here: `[self.coreDataManager.managedObjectContext save:&error];`.

Comment: are you doing this on a background thread? Where are you observing the didChangeNotification?

Comment: @Volker I update the tableview after the new product is added. I guess should be the problem while updating tableview. Let me add the code :) have a look